# Can I use multiplte DB::commit() after DB::beginTransaction() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

This is the example code.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    // Queries
    DB::commit(); // Commit 1
    // Queries
    DB::commit(); // Commit 2
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

As you can see there are two commits. And My questions are :

1. Can I use multiple commits?
2. If I can, how will the roll back work?
3. If my codes get pass commit number 1 and cause error between commit 1 and 2, will it roll back to commit number 1 or all the way up?

Comment: Transactions should be [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) and what does performing multiple commits as in your example actually achieve if you want them to all rollback if any fail? Surely then any database updates would be covered by a single commit?

Comment: I honestly have never tried this, so I'm not sure if (or how) it would work, but I agree with Peppermintology; there shouldn't be a reason you need to perform multiple commits in a single transaction.

Comment: Queries before commit 1 is for some basic inserts but the codes between between commit 1 and commit 2 contains third party app API call and queries. My objective is to not roll back commit 1 if there is an error with API call. Or should I just use separate transaction?